# App to store hours of operation of favorite places in town

Tags: time-management, maps, bookmark

I'm looking for an app that will let me store the addresses and hours of operation of my favorite shops in town. Ous there any such app for Android / what should I be using for this and what would the advantages of that be? (I currently just store these in a file under Google drive). Thanks.

Comment: Are'nt there already some aggregation websites for this kind of information in your area? If not, evaluate this as a business case..

Comment: "what would the advantages of that be" - that part of the sentence doesn't make it a good question for this site. You should already know what you want and why you want it. We can then (maybe) tell you, what fits your requirements.